# Seaborn module install in spyder

Tags: seaborn, spyder

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\PeterSelvarajJ\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_5760\3062450614.py", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
    import seaborn as sn

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seaborn'
```

Comment: Have you installed `seaborn` (e.g. `pip install seaborn`)?

Comment: Yes i did install

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. All packages are installed as precompiled binaries. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/). **If you are using Anaconda, do not use `pip` to install packages that exist within the `conda` ecosystem.** Use `conda install package`. Only use `pip` if the package is not available with `conda install`. Using `pip` can potentially wreck your installation because `pip` and `conda` do not manage dependencies in the same way.

Comment: spyder is included with Anaconda

Comment: Yes thanks. But Anaconda do not have latest version of Spyder so what to do..

Comment: `conda update spyder` after installing Anaconda. Or `conda update --all`

Comment: The `defaults` anaconda channel can be very slow at updating packages, and thus also Spyder. You could try using `conda-forge` channel instead. It appears you are on Windows @PeterJ, and I can recommend using the installers for Spyder (https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases) instead of using Spyder from the full Anaconda distribution. Then read this: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment to connect the installed spyder to virtual environments where you can install whatever packages you need (such as seaborn).